# How to call a method in for loop like so

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to call the function animate dealing to player each time the for loop runs.

```
  -(void)animateDealingToPlayer:(Player *)player withDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
self.frame = CGRectMake(-100.0f, -100.0f, CardWidth, CardHeight);
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);


NSArray *position = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)],                               
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],                                             
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],                         
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)],                          
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)],                                                   


                     nil];              


for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    NSValue *value = [position objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));

    _angle = [self angleForPlayer:player];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                          delay:delay
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {





         self.center = point;              



         self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_angle);
     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Right now it is rewriting self.center over and over until it gives out the 5th object index instead of calling all of the index numbers individually.For example instead of dealing cards at all of the points it is dealing only at (200,100). I need some way to call animaitedealingwithplayer each time so it will deal at all the points,but how do I do that? Will appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: why are you setting the center and transform on `self` instead of some player object?

Comment: Im not going to post the whole code, but it needs to be like this. Since there is multiple players.

Comment: Try changing just element 5's position - does it now animate there?  I think the problem is that you are animating one element (the dealt 'card') 5 times - I don't know if you are allowed to stack up animations like that; either the LAST one is the only one used, or all animations apply at the same time to the card.

Comment: Only the last one is used. I tried it myself. I have to figure out some way for it to call dealt cards 5 times in between each cgpoint.

Comment: Right, all of them happen at the same time so you only see the last one.  You need to do the first one, and then in the completion block of it either start the second one or call a function which will start the next one in the series.

Comment: May you show me an example (will give you a check mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating multiple animation blocks that apply to a single view element, and you are applying these all at once.

Instead, you can cause the animation block to trigger another animation on completion.

There is an example in the [Apple View Programming Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1): "*Listing 4-2 shows an example of an animation block that uses a completion handler to initiate a new animation after the first one finishes*"

I'm posting the example here so you can get a feel for it, but go read the documentation!:

```
- (IBAction)showHideView:(id)sender
{
    // Fade out the view right away
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay: 0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
             thirdView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Wait one second and then fade in the view
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 delay: 1.0
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                    thirdView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
        }];
}
```

In your example, you should probably (in pseudocode):

```
// center card on dealer
Animate: ^{
   // move card to player1
}, completion: ^{
   // center card on dealer
   Animate: ^{
     // move card to player2
   }, completion: ^{
     //center 
     // animate again, and again etc.
   }
}
```